# Parse and extract the comment counts from the JSON data, compute the sum of the numbers in the file and print the sum

Tags: python, json

I am learning to work with JSON data using Python, and I'm stuck in an   assignment which requests Parse and extract the comment counts from the JSON   data, compute the sum of the numbers in the file and print the sum.
[enter image description here][1]

My code is not working. I got this error  SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file newky1.py on line 5, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details.
I have already checked the ref , but I couldn’t solve the problem. Can someone explain to me how to do it?

Comment: You should post a minimal complete verifiable example of what you have written so far

Comment: What does the comment look like? I thought json has no built-in comment type...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I think something has gone wrong with your post uploads so that nobody will be able to help you with because we don't have the source files. I would suggest you include a sample of the JSON, your code to parse it, and the error traceback. When you write/edit a post you will see several tools to edit these easily to match other well-received posts on here. Currently this is unanswerable.